# Windows Azure - access webrole local storage from separate workerrole

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-web-roles

I'm running an application on windows azure, the MVC views need to be dynamic, I started by storing them as records in the database, but am quite keen to move them to a physical location.

My concept was to create the physical file via code... which worked great and speeds up the page load dramatically. This was of course before I realised that the files were only available for the duration of the role

Next I looked at a start up task to create the files when the role was started - however I then realised that any separate instances weren't going to sync up unless I monitored the database for changes.

So I moved from a start up task to a function in the run method of the role that checks the database every 10 minutes to see if changes have occurred. The problem is that this seems to choke up the application (at least in the warm up stage).

Ideally I would like to move the run function to it's own worker role that can sit there and push files out to web role instances, but I'm unsure on how I would go about accessing the web roles local storage from the worker role. Can anybody tell me whether this is actually possible? and hopefully point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Just to clarify what I'm trying to achieve

-View is created in user interface running on web role and stored in database
-Separate web role (front end) has clientside application with virtualpath provider pointing Views requests to local storage (localresource)
-separate worker role to create View structure and load this into clientside web role local storage

Comment: I have deep concern of creating a solution based on Local Storage which may disappear at any time. I would consider to think something which is not depend on Local Storage first and if it is must, the keep the code inside the same machine where the local storage is while changing the machine size to larger VM. It is just not a good design overall.

Comment: My understanding of local storage is that it is (at least) as persistent as the role itself (ie if the role is lost or recycled then local storage would need to be recreated but so would the role so filesetup can be done in the role as a start up task) storing the files in a more persistant location would be nice but as far as  I can see blob storage can only be accessed via http / https rather than via a file path which has a negative impact on my virtual path provider (I've tried), thanks for your input :) the design is a work in progress.

Comment: and then I discover the azure clouddrive and wonder where it's been all my life.

Comment: Sure Cloud Drive is one great option in which you can mount Cloud Drive write/read at one role and read at multiple roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have the exact same possibilities as if you where working with separate Windows Server 2008 R2 instances.

My best guess would be to create a web service or any standard application that can be called from an external location that creates the actual files on your local disk (from the paramters that are passed to it) and call this web service from the worker role periodically.

Of course there are many other workarounds, but I don't think there is any standardized way to access your local storage from a separate role in Azure.

Comment: Makes sense. a web service could work. I've seen virtualpathprovider implementations that pull views from zip folders so potentially I could do the view creation / folder structure on a separate role instance and zip it, then download the zip folder to local storage and serve the views directly from there. Thanks